# Powerline adaptor overheating

Tags: overheating, powerline-networking

I'm currently using a 500Mbps powerline adaptor and I believe it has been constantly overheating from time to time. It stops working once every few hours and it gets extremely warm.

However it resumes functionality after unplugging it and plugging it.

What should I do to resolve this issue? Should I just get a new one? And if I do should I get a 200Mbps instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try drilling some holes in the plastic housing to allow some air to flow.  It might save you a few bucks on buying a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Different manufacturers use different components....

...I have seen quite a few "mini" powerline adapters that overheat... All I can really suggest is try a big chunky one or a different manufacturer and hopefully it will stop your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the adapters stop working because of overheating, then surely this is a case of guarantee/warranty. Bring it back to the seller and buy another, better product. Be assured, this is not generally a problem of 500 Mbps adapters.